# MySQL how to join tables on two fields

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables with `date` and `id` fields. I want to join on both fields.  I tried

```
JOIN t2 ON CONCAT(t1.id, t1.date)=CONCAT(t2.id, t2.date)
```

that works, but it is very slow. is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

```
JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id AND t1.date=t2.date
```

Answer (score 47):

```
JOIN t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id AND t2.date = t1.date)
```

Answer (score 33):

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
JOIN t2 USING (id, date)
```

perhaps you'll need to use 'INNER JOIN' or
'WHERE t2.id is not null'
if you want results only matching both conditions

Comment: Basically, slowness is because concrete calculates new values that has no indexes so direct conditions should be faster.
if even this query would be slow again, check is indexes exists, and sometimes creation one index for 2 fields also makes sense.