# SQL JOIN query syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I store purchases, and a table where I store products.

Each row in the *purchases* table can contain up to 9 products ids (8 can be empty)

```
id, foo, bar, baz, product_1_id, product_2_id, product_3_id, etc...
```

Now I need to query all the fields of that *purchases* table, to display in a html page.

I can't display only the products ids, so I need to find the corresponding product_name in the *products* table.

The SQL query is giving me a hard time.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you just have a products table, instead of limiting a purchase to nine products?

Comment: Can you redesign the database to use a join table?

Comment: "Each row in the purchases table can contain up to 9 products ids (8 can be empty)". Typically this would be stored in a separate table, "purchase_item" or "purchase_product". I guess "purchase" is not really a good name since that refers to one individual item. Classic names are "purchase_order" and "purchase_order_item" or "purchase_order_line". The problem with your design is that it's not flexible (only up to 9 products per purchase) and that it is hard to query. You'll need a join for each potential product per purchase. With a separate purchase_order_item table you need just one.

Comment: I wonder what message you'll send to the user when he/she adds a 10th product to the order. "Sorry but we want to sell you only 9 items?" :)

Comment: Your comments are right, I must admit. BUT, if someone ever wants to buy ten products at once, I'd be happy to rethink everything from scratch, free of charge... ;)

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the product names, I'd try this:

```
SELECT t2.product_name as product_name_1, t3.product_name as product_name_2, t4.product_name as product_name_1, [...]
FROM purchases as t1
JOIN products as t2 ON(t1.product_1_id = t2.product_id)
LEFT JOIN products as t3 ON(t1.product_2_id = t3.product_id)
LEFT JOIN products as t4 ON(t1.product_3_id = t4.product_id)
[...]
WHERE t1.id = ...
```

but this will probably be VERY slow, you might want to restructure your database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join with Products table 9 times. But consider normalisation

```
select id, foo, bar, baz, p1.product_name, p2.product_name, p3.product_name, 
  etc...  
from purchases as pur
left join products as p1 on pur.product_1_id=p1.product_id
left join products as p2 on pur.product_2_id=p2.product_id
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

in sql you can use like this..

```
 select *,PM.Product_id,P.Product_name from purchase_mst PM, product P where   
 PM.Product_id1=P.Product_id1 and PM.Product_id2=P.Product_id2 etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

With a properly normalized design you'd have: product, purchase_Order and purchase_order_line and the query would simply be:

```
SELECT     ...
FROM       purchase_order
INNER JOIN purchase_order_line
ON         purchase_order.id = purchase_order_line.purchase_order_id
INNER JOIN product
ON         purchase_order_line.product_id = product.id
```

Comment: Thank you Roland. I'd love to learn. Where can I find informations about properly normalized designs ?

Comment: there is *a lot* of stuff on the web, just google it. For example, this is a reasonable start http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm and so is this http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/179103-relational-database-design-normalization/

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/179103-relational-database-design-normalization/ is really helpful. Thanks Roland.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier if you had a table connecting *purchases* and *products* with two columns *product_id, purchase_id*.

But still, I guess you can try something like this :

```
SELECT pr1.name
 FROM purchases pur1, products pr1
WHERE pur1.product_1_id = pr1.id
UNION ALL
SELECT pr2.name
 FROM purchases pur2, products pr2
WHERE pur2.product_1_id = pr2.id
UNION ALL
-- and so on until
SELECT pr9.name
 FROM purchases pur9, products pr9
WHERE pur9.product_9_id = pr9.id
```

Although this looks pretty scary and I would strongly suggest rethinking your database design.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

Select purchase.*, product.* from purchase join product on id1=id, id2=id... Etc.

Read this:

[MySQL how to join tables on two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498197/mysql-join-on-two-fields)