# Select data from multiple tables for display

Tags: php, sql

Bad Code

```
<?php 
    include 'database.php';
    $pdo = Database::connect();   
    $sql = 'SELECT id, name, date, installer, salesman, category, status FROM workorder JOIN customers ON customers.id=workorder.name'; 

    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['date'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['installer'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['salesman'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['category'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['status'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td width=250>';
        echo '<a class="btn" href="read.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
        echo '&nbsp;';
        echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
        echo '&nbsp;';
        echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    Database::disconnect();
?>
```

End Goal : Pull the First Name/Last Name from one table represented by the 'name' field in the workorder table via join & foreach functions.

Correct Code :

```
<?php 
                       include 'database.php';
                       $pdo = Database::connect();   


                                $sql = 'SELECT workorder.id, FName, LName, name, date, installer, salesman, category, status FROM workorder JOIN customers ON customers.id=workorder.name'; 
                                $rows = $pdo->query($sql);

                       foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['FName'] ." ".$row['LName']; '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['date'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['installer'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['salesman'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['category'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['status'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td width=250>';
                                echo '<a class="btn" href="read.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                                echo '&nbsp;';
                                echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                                echo '&nbsp;';
                                echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                                echo '</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                                }

                       Database::disconnect();
                      ?>
```

Added "FName, LName" to the SELECT command(because apparently this is callable after you join the customer table) and altered the foreach function to include "FName", and "LName" respectively.  Added "workorder.id" instead of just "id" possibly to keep the id from the workorder table from conflicting with the id from the customers table.

THANK YOU FOR EVERYONE's HELP!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL how to join tables on two fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498197/mysql-how-to-join-tables-on-two-fields)

Comment: `select * from workorder w inner join customers c on w.name = c.id order by w.date desc`

Comment: I think you need a foreign key association with customers table.  You could then have a query with a join to customers table to pull the name of the customer using the customer_id in workorder table.

Comment: @paqogomez I tried that and I get the following error : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @user2411276 what do you mean a foreign key?  how would I implement that, and identify the "key" as the customer tables name, and pull it with the workorders 'name' that is associated with the customers 'id'?

Comment: Dont do a `select *`, name your columns.  Only pull the data you want to display.

Comment: @paqogomez I want to select every column from workorder for display, that is why I used select *, I will do as you said(just to keep from being lazy), but how will that affect the result?

Comment: I think that error is caused by two fields of the same name in different tables.

Comment: @paqogomez just finished doing as you said, to no avail.  the only identical field across both tables is the "id" column

Comment: I dont think you have a good handle on what your data looks like, or what fields you want to show.  Which customer fields are you wanting to show?

Comment: You need to add customer_id column to the workorder table and create foreign key association to customers table. Use alter table to add customer_id  column and foreign key relationship to customers table.

Comment: @paqogomez I have 6 columns for workorder, one of which is named 'name' and is associated with the 'id' of my customers table.  My customers table has 8 columns, of which 'FName' and 'LName' are a part.  I want to be able to use the 'name' from the workorders table to associate with the corresponding 'id' from the customers table, and then pull the 'FName' and 'LName' from that 'id' to put in 'name's place in the workorder table.  Sorry for being so confusing.

Comment: ok. you already have association.  just use the sql query @paqogomez gave before to get the customer name.  Also another suggestion would be to change the column name 'name' to customer_id in the workorder table if you are actually storing customer_id in it.

Comment: @paqogomez I altered my question with my current code, and issues.  I think the issue might come into question when the "foreach" part of the code tries to execute.

Comment: add FName, LName  columns in your select query

Comment: @user2411276 the FName, LName columns are exclusive to the "customers" table, not the workorder table

Comment: since you have a join in your sql query you could retreieve the columns from customers table

Comment: can you try this: before the foreach loop: `$res = $pdo->query($sql); echo gettype($res);` and post the result?
btw is this MySql?

Comment: Glad @Steven was able to help you understand! (+1) Its not necessary to add your solution to your question.  Steven's answer does that.  If his answer is missing something, edit it in or leave a note for him.  Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add FName and LName columns to your select query. In the ouput part change your code to retrieve FName and LName.

SQL:

```
try{
$sql = "SELECT workorder.id, FName, LName, name, date, installer, salesman, category, status FROM workorder JOIN customers ON customers.id=workorder.name"; 
$rows = $pdo->query($sql);
}catch(PDOException $pe){
var_dump($pe);
}
```

Instead of

```
echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>';
```

you need to do

```
echo '<td>'. $row['FName'] ." ".$row['LName'] '</td>';
```

Comment: tried this, and got the following error : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\workorders.php on line 39, line 39 : foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {

Comment: update your code part of the question with the new sql query you are using

Comment: still using the following :$sql = 'SELECT id, name, date, installer, salesman, category, status FROM workorder JOIN customers USING customers.id=workorder.name;';                            Am I supposed to add FName and LName in there somewhere?

Comment: For clarification : workorder table includes(id,name,date,installer,salesman,category,status) and customers table includes(id,FName,LName,etc.,etc.,etc)

Comment: yes. change sql to -  SELECT id, FName,LName, name, date, installer, salesman, category, status FROM workorder JOIN customers on customers.id=workorder.name;

Comment: still get the : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 39 (foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {

Comment: and what is the output?  verify that there is data in both tables that match. otherwise you will get empty resultset

Comment: if i bypass the "foreach" and execute "echo $pdo->query($sql); I get no results.  I do not know what you mean by data needing to match in both tables, the only matching values are the 'name'(workorder) to the 'id'(customers)  The idea is to match the above(say 'name' = 15, = 'id'15 of customer id, and then pull the FName and LName from customers table id "15" and put in the place of 'name' in workorder table

Comment: i have edited my answer to show the sql query.  change your code and let me know what you get.

Comment: I added a table diagram to demonstrate

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''workorder.id, FName, LName, n' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\workorders.php on line 39

Comment: the sql didnot have double quotes. check it now

Comment: changed your code to this :         try{
$sql = 'SELECT workorder.id, FName, LName, name, date, installer, salesman, category, status FROM workorder JOIN customers ON customers.id=workorder.name'; 
$rows = $pdo->query($sql);
}catch(PDOException $pe){
var_dump($pe);
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75325/discussion-between-steven-and-user2411276).