# SQL query to ask for one value only

Tags: mysql, sql

The tables given are these:

```
MAKLER (MaklerID, Name, registriertSeit)
IMMOBILIE(ImmoID, Typ, qm, AnzahlZimmer, Baujahr, Energiewert, Preis,
angebotenVon, Provision, liegtIn)
```

"angebotenVon" is the foreign key to "MaklerID"

I am trying to write a query where I check if a "Makler" sells an imbolie with the type "Haus" and not probably other types of "Immobilien". If the Makler sells immobilien of the type "Haus" and "Wohnungen" I don't want to select them.

My solution that far looks like this:

```
SELECT makler.*
FROM makler JOIN
     immobilie
     ON immobilie.angebotenVon = makler.MaklerID
WHERE immobilie.Typ = "Haus" AND immobilie.Typ != '%'
```

So that if "Haus" is inside the table immobilie, and the "Makler" doesn't sell anything else, the complete makler-table gets shown. But I'm very unsure about this solution.

Comment: I guess you are using a filter query, try immobilie.Typ LIKE "%Haus%" and remove immobilie.Typ != '%' because it is redundant

Comment: But it will show me "Makler" if they have "Immobile" of the type "Haus" and any other. But I need all "Makler" that sell ONLY immobile of the type "Haus". I hope I can explain what I mean.

Comment: So you mean the "Makler" is your primary data and you want to filter the data for "Haus" ONLY not "Immobilien"?

Comment: "Haus" is a possible value in immobilie.type. If the Makler sells immobilie type "Haus" I want to select him. If he has types of "Haus" and maybe something else, I don't want to select him.
I updated my Question.

Comment: Try using immobilie.Typ = '%Haus' combine your two where clause into this one. I assume that all your data type is string.

Comment: There is some confusion so you can post same data and desired output to make your question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use join on multi field, as take [reference from.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498197/mysql-how-to-join-tables-on-two-fields) or simple change the query to

```
SELECT makler.* 
FROM makler 
JOIN immobilie ON immobilie.angebotenVon = makler.MaklerID 
      AND immobilie.Typ = "Haus"
```

Comment: update your question to provide proper description and table references or say table structure.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, you seem to want `not exists`:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM makler m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM immobilie i
                  WHERE i.angebotenVon = m.MaklerID AND
                        i.Typ <> 'Haus'
                 );
```

If you want to guarantee that "Haus" is in the table (`immobilie` might have no matching records), then use `exists`:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM makler m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM immobilie i
                  WHERE i.angebotenVon = m.MaklerID AND
                        i.Typ <> 'Haus'
                 ) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM immobilie i
              WHERE i.angebotenVon = m.MaklerID AND
                    i.Typ = 'Haus'
             );
```